# data cannot be resolved to type

Tags: java, variables, parameters, compiler-errors, boolean

i need to do this for my homework, however, when i compile it says that my variables in the print data cannot be resolved to types, what am i doing wrong? I also need to create a tester class for this.

```
public class PayCalculator


{
  private double hourlyRate;
  private double hoursWorked;

  /**
   * Two parameter constructor
   * Add hourlyRate and hoursWorked
   * @param the hourly rate
   * @param the hours worked
   */
  public PayCalculator(double aHourlyRate, double aHoursWorked)
  {
    hourlyRate = aHourlyRate;
    hoursWorked = aHoursWorked;
  }

  /**
   * sets the hourly rate
   * @return hourlyRate
   */ 
  public void setHourlyRate(double aHourlyRate)
  {
    hourlyRate = aHourlyRate;
  }

  /**
   * gets the hourly rate
   * @param hourlyRate
   */
  public double getHourlyRate()
  {
    return hourlyRate;
  }

  /**
   * sets the hours worked
   * @return hoursWorked
   */ 
  public void setHoursWorked(double aHoursWorked)
  {
    hoursWorked = aHoursWorked;
  }

  /**
   * gets the hours worked
   * @param hours worked
   */
  public double getHoursWorked()
  {
    return hoursWorked;
  }



  public boolean workedOvertime()
  {
    if (hoursWorked > 40)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else 
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public double numHoursOvertime()
  {
    if (hoursWorked > 40)
    {
      return hoursWorked - 40;
    }
    else 
    {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  public double calculateGrossPay()
  {
    if (hourlyRate  <= 10.25)
    {
      if (hourlyRate <= 40)
        return hourlyRate * hoursWorked;
    }
    else 
    {  
      double grossPay = ((40 * hourlyRate) + ((hourlyRate * 2) * hoursWorked - 40));
      return grossPay;
    }

    if (hoursWorked <= 60)
    {
      return hourlyRate * hoursWorked;
    }
    else
    {
      return 60 * hourlyRate;
    }
  }

  public double determineTaxRate(double grossPay)
  {
    if (grossPay >= 800)
    {
      double tax = 0;
      tax = grossPay * 0.37;
      return tax;
    }
    else if ( grossPay >= 400)
    {
      double tax = 0;
      tax = grossPay * 0.22;
      return tax;
    }
    else
    {
      double tax = 0;
      tax = grossPay * 0.12;
      return tax;
    }
  }

  public double calculateNetPay(double grossPay, double tax)
  {
    double calculateNetPay = grossPay - tax;
    return calculateNetPay;
  }

  public void printData()
  {
    System.out.println("Hours Worked: " + hoursWorked);
    System.out.println("Hourly rate: " + hourlyRate);
    System.out.println("Number of hours of overtime worked: " + numHoursOvertime);
    System.out.println("Worked overtime? " + workedOvertime);
    System.out.println("Gross pay: " + calculateGrossPay);
    System.out.println("Tax Rate: " + determineTaxRate);
    System.out.println("Net Pay: " + calculateNetPay);
  }


}
```

Comment: where exactly in this code is your error?

Comment: numHoursOvertime workedOvertime are methods. You cannot just call them like this!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just call the `methods` just by their name. Call them like below.

```
numHoursOvertime()
workedOvertime()
determineTaxRate(10) // example
calculateNetPay(10, 10) // example
```

You can learn more about methods [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Answer (score 0):

The methods cannot be used in the `System.out.println();` call. instead, in the method, make new `int`'s and assign them using the methods, and then print them out after that. for example:

```
int a = calculateTax();
System.out.println("tax: " + a);
```

Answer (score 0):

numHoursOvertime workedOvertime are methods. You cannot just call them like this!

```
numHoursOvertime()
workedOvertime()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your confusing method names and variable names. For example,  use

```
numHoursOvertime()
```

and not

```
numHoursOvertime
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the methods with parenthesis `hoursWorked()`. One other possible error I see in the code is in method `public double determineTaxRate(double grossPay)` the variable `tax` is not defined